# How reliable is NDB's put()?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm having some strange behavior with my models.

I have Event model, which keeps tracks of events. And an "Aggregate" model, which stores an aggregate of records of model A, grouped by date.

```
class Event(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=UserProfile)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    event_type = ndb.StringProperty()
    is_aggregated = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)

class Aggregate(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=UserProfile)
    date = ndb.DateProperty()
    aggregates = ndb.PickleProperty(default={})
```

**`Event`** has an `aggregate()` method, like so:

```
def aggregate(self):
    if self.is_aggregated:
        # already aggregated
        return

    # get an existing aggregate
    agg = Aggregate.query(
        Aggregate.user == self.user,
        Aggregate.date == self.date.date()
    ).get()
    if not agg:
        # or create a new one
        agg = Aggregate(
            user=self.user,
            date=self.date.date()
        )
        agg.put()

    # update aggregate's count
    if self.event_type not in agg.aggregates.keys():
        agg.aggregates[self.event_type] = 0
    agg.aggregates[self.event_type] += 1
    agg.put()

    # mark this as aggregated
    self.is_aggregated = True
    self.put()
```

Now, in my handlers, every time a new `Event` is created, I call its `aggregate` method.
But there's some discrepancy with the numbers.

For example, I have 20 `Event` records with the `date` between `2013-10-10 00:00:00` and `2013-10-10 23:59:59` and `event_type = "add"`, all of them have `is_aggregated = True`. That would imply that the `aggregate` method executed successfully for each.

But when I view the corresponding `Aggregate` record with the `date = 2013-10-10`, the `aggregates` property doesn't reflect 20 `"add"` events. It only has 16.

What would cause such a discrepancy? How would `self.put()` succeed but `agg.put()` not succeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suppose that you've faced [eventual consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) feature. Every time you're querying Aggregate model it can be retrieved from different datacenters which can contain slightly different versions of Aggregate. Especially if your Event models are created quickly enough.

I would made this way: manually compose string ID of Aggregate model based on user and date and then get it by this ID by Aggregate.get_by_id() (I supposed user has id):

```
# get an existing aggregate
agg_id = str(user.id) + '@' + self.date.date().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
agg = Aggregate.get_by_id(agg_id)
if not agg:
    # or create a new one
    agg = Aggregate(key=ndb.Key(Aggregate, agg_id),
                    user=self.user,
                    date=self.date.date()
    )
    #agg.put() #ALSO, this put is not needed because you has one below
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. Is there a way to verify if it fixes the issue? Also, the doc states entities will be "eventually consistent", but the records I'm querying are several days old. How long does "eventual" mean here?

Comment: "Eventual consistent" means that when you create a new Event you can get Aggregate which doesn't reflect changes from previous Event (for example, 'aggregates' property contains not 3 but 2 items). So you're already updating not a fresh Aggreate, and so on... So, you will never again see "several days old" changes.

Comment: Ah right, makes sense. Thanks. So if I use a key to get the entity, it will ensure that the entity I'm getting is updated? I ask because the docs only show that consistency is achieved by using ancestor queries/groupings.

Comment: Yes, "Remember, if you do a get, an ancestor query, or any operation within a transaction, you will always see the most recently written data." - from the link I gave in answer. I used get_by_id because it is more cost efficient since you're getting only one entity.